# Ж ("zhe") in string theory?

Tags: string-theory, curvature, notation

I was just recently watching a [TED talk about string theory](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSz5BjExs9o), by Thad Roberts, and at around 11:10 into the video he mentions a constant for maximum spacial curvature called "zhe" (the Cyrillic symbol Ж). I had never heard of this before, and I know the use of Cyrillic characters is rare in mathematics, so I decided to Google to to find more information on it and I ended up dry. Does anyone know what the deal with this Ж constant is, and where I could learn more about it? Is this based off some new, obscure research in string theory?

Comment: Hi user1946002, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! I edited the corrections you mentioned into the question, but you can always do that yourself (and are encouraged to do so) if you have more things to fix.

Comment: In his next 'slide' he writes the fine structure constant as $\alpha = 1/(4\pi)$ * Ж^2 (the exponent might be a three instead of a two, not easy to read).

Comment: For posterity, Thad Roberts has no idea what the hell he’s talking about. He’s a vapid self-promoter with a following on more credulous sites, like Quora.

Comment: @knzhou for what it's worth, I just looked at his Quora page (I'd never heard of him before), and I'd like to object to the point that he has a following there: he doesn't. I can't find any papers (co-) authored by him on arxiv, and a google search reveals nothing by him.

Comment: Since this question is getting bumped up again, I guess there's another thing that should be said for posterity: don't trust generic TEDx talks, _especially_ ones about subjects that the audience knows little about. They have no quality control mechanisms whatsoever. The main TED event is a little better though it also screws up sometimes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Is this based off some new, obscure research in string theory?*

No.  This is fringe science.  There is no mathematical connection to string theory.

It is remarkably bad behavior for this man to set himself up as a public intellectual -- giving TED talks, making a website comparing himself with Einstein, writing a popular science book -- when he has no scientific papers describing his results.  (He has a pdf on his website.  It contains no details of any significance.)

Looks like TED's decided brand dilution is OK.